# What is the best resolution obtainable by ultrasonic non destructive testing?

Tags: ultrasound

What is the best resolution obtainable by ultrasonic non destructive testing? I understand it depends on frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution depends on the material you are using and the frequency $f$ applied. An approximation for the resolution is given by half of the wavelength $$\lambda = \frac{c}{f}.$$

The sonic speed $c$, in meters per second, for some materials, is given by the following list:

- Steel: 5900
- Aluminum: 6320
- Brass: 4430
- Lead: 2160
- Water: 1480
- Air: 330.

Depending on the mechanism that is used to generate the ultrasonic sound waves (piezoelectric effect: $f=200 \text{ kHz} \ldots 20 \text{ MHz}$ or megnetorestricitve effect: $f=10 \text{ kHz} \ldots 200 \text{ kHz}$) you will get different resolutions. A common frequency range for metals is between $0.2 \text{ MHz}$ up to $20 \text{ MHz}$. **The resulting resolution is then $0.1 \text{ mm}$ for steel.**